# React-redux action is returning before async action is complete

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a React Native app using redux and I'd like my action to set the GPS coordinates so I have them available in the store. You can see my console logs in the code, and 'action returning' is logged before 'has coordinates', which is the problem.

Component:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1}} onPress={() => {
    this.props.setLocation();
}}>
```

Action.js

```
export function setLocation(){

    let coords = {
        latitude:0,
        longitude:0,
        navigatorError:''
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        console.log('has coordinates');
        coords['latitude'] = position.coords.latitude
        coords['longitude'] = position.coords.longitude
        coords['navigatorError'] = null
      },
      (error) => coords['navigatorError'] = error.message,
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
      );

    console.log('action returning');
    return {
      type: 'set_location',
      payload: coords
    };
};
```

Reducer.js

```
export default (state = null, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'set_location':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not actually using redux-thunk in this project, I'm not sure if it's appropriate for what I need here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` and `await` to accomplish this. Basically, you need to `await` the coords to be returned from your asynchronous call.

Something like this:

```js
export async function setLocation(){

    let coords = {
        latitude:0,
        longitude:0,
        navigatorError:''
    };

    await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            console.log('has coordinates');
            coords['latitude'] = position.coords.latitude
            coords['longitude'] = position.coords.longitude
            coords['navigatorError'] = null
        },
        (error) => coords['navigatorError'] = error.message,
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
        );

    console.log('action returning');
    return {
        type: 'set_location',
        payload: coords
    };
};
```

Documentation on async/await can be found [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Comment: I'm trying this, I get: `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Comment: This is because your `getCurrentPosition` function should technically be handled by a side effect library (Thunk or Sagas, for example). Actions should pretty much never do anything more than return a type and payload. Anything else should be handled by a side effect library.

Comment: The tutorials I'm looking at seem to use `axios` and `then()`, which isn't appropriate for my case. How can I get my action to dispatch after `getCurrentPosition()` is done?

Comment: Essentially, you would set up two actions. One for dispatching to fetch the positions, and then one to dispatch that the fetch has succeeded.update the state (one for an error case is probably a good idea). If you want, I can show you how this would all fit together. However, I am more familiar with Saga than Thunk, but I imagine the pattern wouldn't be much different.